# Rotate Font Awesome Icon On Click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to make a Font Awesome chevron rotate 180º on click.

Here's the fiddle of [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3v2egwfs/1/) that has what I've tried so far. I also wanted it to spin around the center so I used this other [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22908242/rotate-image-around-center-css3).

**HTML**

```
<div class="fa fa-chevron-up"><a href="#">^</a></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.rotate {
-webkit-animation: spin1 2s  linear;
-moz-animation: spin1 2s  linear;
-o-animation: spin1 2s  linear;
-ms-animation: spin1 2s  linear;
animation: spin1 2s  linear;

-webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
-moz-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
-o-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
transform-origin: 50% 50%;
width: 256px;
height: 256px;
}

@-webkit-keyframes spin1 {
0% { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);}
100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);}
}
@-moz-keyframes spin1 {
0% { -moz-transform: rotate(0deg); }
100% { -moz-transform: rotate(180deg);}
}
@-o-keyframes spin1 {
0% { -o-transform: rotate(0deg);}
100% { -o-transform: rotate(180deg);}
}
@-ms-keyframes spin1 {
0% { -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);}
100% { -ms-transform: rotate(180deg);}
}
@-keyframes spin1 {
0% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
100% { transform: rotate(180deg);}
}
```

**JS**

```
$(".fa-chevron-up").click(function(){
 $(this).toggleClass("rotate")  ; 
})
```

Comment: So what's your problem?

Comment: When you click on the link in the fiddle, it doesn't trigger the JS or appear to perform any action

Comment: jquery is missing from your fiddle.  it works fine when it's there

Comment: Thanks @kellycode. Do you know if there's any way to get it to rotate for 180º in the same place and stay that way until the user clicks again when it reverts back to original state?

Answer (score 108, accepted):

I believe it would be easier to do this with CSS transitions:

**CSS**

```
.rotate{
    -moz-transition: all 2s linear;
    -webkit-transition: all 2s linear;
    transition: all 2s linear;
}

.rotate.down{
    -ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(180deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
    transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$(".rotate").click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass("down"); 
});
```

**[Demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/koala_dev/3v2egwfs/7/)**

Comment: +1 It's possible to avoid transitioning `all` if you list all the possible prefixes. `-ms-transform` can also be added for IE9, although it won't transition (as it's not supported).

Comment: Very usefull, try to think about sometimes the Transform dose not work if you do not add: display: block or display: inline-block

Comment: Very much helpful! Appreciate it

Comment: Same CSS solution just using vanilla JS instead  

    document.querySelectorAll('.rotate').forEach(i => { 
      i.addEventListener('click', () => {  i.classList.toggle("down");  });});