# Is it possible to rotate font awesome 5 icons on click?

Tags: css, font-awesome-5

I would like to rotate an fontawesome 5 icon (which is in an panel) 180 degree on click.

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne">
            <div class="panel-title clearfix">
                <span> Hello world</span>
                <i class="fas fa-chevron-down"></i>
              </div>
            </a>
          </div>
```

I'm using SVG + JS version of Font Awesome.

Comment: Looks like this has been solved [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26173376/rotate-font-awesome-icon-on-click)

Comment: i dont think it works on font awesome 5

Comment: it's the same logic but you need to apply rotation to the SVG that is generated to replace the `i`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my solution, It's not a perfect solution, as I had to add a id and click listener to the `accordion-toggle` class.

After that, I target the generated svg class `.svg-inline--fa` to toggle the chevron up and down classes.

```js
var atag = document.querySelector('#atag');

atag.addEventListener('click', on_click);

function on_click() {
  var elem = document.querySelector('#atag .svg-inline--fa');
  elem.classList.toggle("fa-chevron-up");
  elem.classList.toggle("fa-chevron-down");
}
```

```html
<script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.2.0/js/all.js" integrity="sha384-4oV5EgaV02iISL2ban6c/RmotsABqE4yZxZLcYMAdG7FAPsyHYAPpywE9PJo+Khy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading">
    <a class="accordion-toggle" id="atag" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne">
      <div class="panel-title clearfix">
        <span> Hello world</span>
        <i class="fas fa-chevron-down "></i>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
```

Comment: I like this simple idea, appreciated

Answer (score 3):

In order to rotate a Font Awesome 5 icon you need to manipulate its inner SVG element.

**HTML**

```
<i class="fas fa-chevron-up transition" onClick="toggleView(event)"></i>
```

or in Angular 8

```
<fa-icon icon="chevron-up" class="transition" (click)="toggleView($event)"></fa-icon>
```

**CSS**

```
.transition > svg {
    -moz-transition: transform 0.3s;
    -webkit-transition: transform 0.3s;
    transition: transform 0.3s;
}

.flip-v { /* flip vertically 180 deg */
    -moz-transform: rotate(180deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
    transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
toggleView(event) {
    //currentTarget: icon
    //currentTarget.firstChild: inner SVG
    $(event.currentTarget.firstChild).toggleClass('flip-v');
}
```

**Note:** this solution assumes the use of JQuery and Font Awesome 5